# uploading files into different destinations using the php POST variable sent from a form?

Tags: php, forms, variables, file-upload, subdirectory

I am trying to allow the admin to create a new folder and upload multiple pictures files into a new user account. This user can then have access to this folder with assigned user/password. BUT when changing the code in the upload.php it will not upload the files and just refreshes. Below is the form and variables that passes the hidden value for the directory name for the files to be placed.

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
?>
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Image upload</title>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Boogaloo' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link rel="StyleSheet" href="../../custom.css" type="text/css"/>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/multiupload.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var config = {
    support : "image/jpg,image/png,image/bmp,image/jpeg,image/gif",     // Valid file formats
    form: "demoFiler",                  // Form ID
    dragArea: "dragAndDropFiles",       // Upload Area ID
    uploadUrl: "upload.php"             // Server side upload url
}
$(document).ready(function(){
    initMultiUploader(config);
});
</script>
<link href="css/style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body lang="en">
<div id="content">
<?php require_once $header;
        $sql_query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM clients WHERE `id` = $id");
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql_query))
            {
            $fullname = $row['firstname'] . ' ' . $row['lastname'];
                if (!file_exists('uploads/' . $fullname )) 
                {
                mkdir('uploads/' . $fullname, 0777, true);
                }
            }
 ?>
<h1 class="title">Multiple Drag and Drop File Upload</h1>
<div id="dragAndDropFiles" class="uploadArea">
    <h1>Drop Images Here</h1>
</div>
<form name="demoFiler" id="demoFiler" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="multiUpload" id="multiUpload" multiple />
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $fullname; ?>" name="fullname" id="fullname"/>
<input type="submit" name="submitHandler" id="submitHandler" value="Upload" class="buttonUpload" />
</form>
<div class="progressBar">
    <div class="status"></div></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And then the upload.php that the form is passed to, I have changed the value after upload/ in numerous ways to see if i can get files uploaded. I thought that this `"uploads/"' . $_POST['fullname'] . '/'`

would work but when the files upload they just keep refreshing and fail.

This is the upload.php

```
<?php
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST"){
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], "uploads/".$_FILES['file']['name'])){
        echo($_POST['index']);
    }
    exit;
}
?>
```

Comment: Try a print_r($_FILES); does it contains any values at all?

Comment: The upload.php does not display on screen. Can you recommend a way of displaying the information thanks

Comment: Using firebug you can see what response you get.

Comment: i believe this is what you mean.. firephp response:<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined variable: POST in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\files\allchorn\client\photo\upload.php</b> on line <b>3</b><br />
NPBEA.tvs

Comment: This means the $_POST['index'] param is not set. Are you sure you are using a browser that supports HTML5 and all Javascript libraries are loaded and of the right version for the script? See top part of documentation: http://www.9lessons.info/2012/09/multiple-file-drag-and-drop-upload.html